# What would be my SqlServer query?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, relational-database

**Table1**

```
P R E Value

X 1 10 1
Y 2 30 2
Z 3 CR 3
X 1 30 4
```

**Table2**

```
P R E Value

X 1 CR 4 
Y 2 10 5
Y 3 CR 6
W 1 30 7
```

Query1 - Merge these two tables. I'm able to achieve this using union clause.

Query2 - On the merged table select all records except for entries where for a combination of P, R & E; there are similar records with the only mismatch of 'E' as 30 & 10, then ignore record with E as 30. In case only 30 is present then consider it.

Conditions:

- 10 & 30 - consider only 10, ignore 30
- 10 - consider it
- 30 - consider it
- CR - consider it
- 10 & CR - consider both
- 30 & CR - consider both
- 10 & 30 & CR - consider 10 & CR

**Expected Output table**

```
P R E Value

X 1 10 1
Z 3 CR 3
X 1 CR 4 
Y 2 10 5
Y 3 CR 6
W 1 30 7
```

**Ignored records**

```
Y 2 30 2
X 1 30 4
```

Comment: Please don't format your entire question as code!  Have edited.

Comment: Using Exclude clause, Where clause. Wasn't successful.

Comment: @SirCrispalot Thank you. I'm learning these tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve your desired result set with the following query.

```
  insert into #Table1
  values ('X','1','10','1'),
         ('Y','2','30','2'),
         ('Z','3','CR','3'),
         ('X','1','30','4')

  insert into #Table2
  values ('X','1','CR','4'),
         ('Y','2','10','5'),
         ('Y','3','CR','6'),
         ('W','1','30','7')


  --Query2
  select * from(
  --Query1
  select * from #Table1 union select * from #Table2) x
  where E != '30' OR 
  (
     E = '30' AND P+':'+R NOT IN 
    (
       --Modified Query1
       select P+':'+R from #Table1 where E = '10' 
       union 
       select P+':'+R  from #Table2 y where E = '10'
     )
   )
   order by Value
```